# How to do a 3D animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, plot, 3d

This is a double question. My main goal is to create an animated 3D plot. I started creating the same plot, but in 2D. But the animation does not work, and I don’t know why. This is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
%matplotlib nbagg

'''
Each one of those are list of numbers: 
x_earth, y_earth, z_earth, x_ryu, y_ryu, z_ryu, x_hay,y_hay,z_hay, vel, dist, t

'''

fig = plt.figure(figsize= (8,4))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot (121)
ax1.grid (True)
ax1.plot (0,0,'yo', markersize=20, label='Sun' )
ax1.set_xlim(min (min (x_earth), min(x_ryu), min(x_hay)), max (max (x_earth), max(x_ryu), max(x_hay)))
ax1.set_ylim(min (min (y_earth), min(y_ryu), min(y_hay)), max (max (y_earth), max(y_ryu), max(y_hay)))
pt1, = ax1.plot ([],[], 'bo', label='Earth')
pt2, = ax1.plot ([],[],'ko', label='Ryugu')
pt3, = ax1.plot ([],[], 'r^', label='Hayabusa 2')
l3, = ax1.plot ([],[], 'r--')
#ax1.legend()

ax2 = fig.add_subplot (122)

ax2.grid(True)
ax2.set_xlim(0, max (t))
ax2.set_ylim(0, max (max (vel), max(dist)))
l4, = ax2.plot ([],[], 'b-', label='Rendezvous Distance')
l5, = ax2.plot ([],[], 'g--', label = 'Hayabusa velocity')
ax2.legend()


def init():    

    pt1.set_data([],[])
    pt2.set_data([],[])
    pt3.set_data([],[])
    l3.set_data([],[])
    l4.set_data([],[])
    l5.set_data([],[])    

    return (pt1,pt2,pt3,l3,l4,l5,)

def animate(i):

    pt1.set_data(x_earth[i],y_earth[i])
    pt2.set_data(x_ryu[i],y_ryu[i])
    pt3.set_data(x_hay[i],y_hay[i])

    l3.set_data(t[:i],dist[:i])
    l4.set_data(t[:i],dist[:i])
    l5.set_data(t[:i],vel[:i])

    return (pt1,pt2,pt3,l3,l4,l5,) 

ani = FuncAnimation (fig, animate, fargs=(pt1,pt2,pt3,l3,l4,l5),frames =len(t),init_func=init,interval=25, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Then, I would like to transform the left subplot into a 3D plot, by adding a third column to the data. But I don’t know how to do that.

Comment: Remove `fargs=(pt1,pt2,pt3,l3,l4,l5),` - that just doesn't make sense if `animate` only takes `i` as input.

Comment: Yes, it worked !! Thanks !!! But in the 3D case, the animation does not work if I try doing it in the same way